# Spring Boot @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) results in InitializationError

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have had this problem for a few days, checked similar questions on this forum and Googled in various ways but could not find an answer.

This is a Spring Boot starter project: I have a class Graphs which is annotated by @Component in a package under "src/main/java":

```
@Component
public class Graphs {
}
```

Then, I created test classes under "src/test/java". One of them (to test Graphs):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import com.example.demo.Graphs;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GraphsTest {   
  @Test
  public void testRun () {
     Graphs graph = new Graphs(); 
  }
}
```

Then I ran testRun in Eclipse (right-click on "testRun"--> Run As --> Junit Test). The result I got was:

```
initializationError [Runner: Junit 4] (0.0001s)
```

The Failure Trace in Eclipse shows the following:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testRun], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testRun(com.example.demoTest.GraphsTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.example.demoTest.GraphsTest,fLeadingIdentifier=testRun]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@1f7030a6
at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

I made a few tweaks without any luck:

1. I bought my Eclipse Oxygen up-to-date, also tried in Eclipse 2018-12 edition, the same result.
2. If I remove @RunWith annotation and run testRun, it produced expected results.
3. I added a Public static void main and ran it as "Java Application", it produced expect results. I guess running it as a Java app bypassed @RunWith(SpringRunner.class).

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you show your imports? See [Eclipse throws java.lang.NullPointerException when running Spring JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469417/eclipse-throws-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-running-spring-junit). See examples and imports from [Spring Boot Testing tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)

Comment: Try to run with empty `testRun() {}` and see what happen

Comment: Test Run "testRun() {}" as Junit Test produced the same (initializationError) result.

Comment: I edited the original post by removing "..." in both original class and the test class to simplifiy the problem. testRun produces the same error as reported.